# How to find all Drupal modules which has dependence

Tags: version-control

I would like to know if it possible to find all contributed modules that depend, for example, on the Subform module.

This information could be useful if you are working with a module, and want to create yours because you don't know that the same module already exists.

Comment: I am not sure how knowing which modules depend from a specific one avoids you create a duplicate module. There could be a module with the same purpose your module has, but that depends from another module, or that doesn't depend from other modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only way, and it is coping all the modules. [Here](http://lin-clark.com/comment/401#comment-401) is opinion of Lin Clark.

Answer (score 2):

That's really easy to do with [Gotta Download Them All](http://drupal.org/sandbox/greggles/1481160). Once you have downloaded all the modules, you can just run a grep command to search the whole contribution space.